# cast from void * to Local<Function>

Tags: c++, casting, v8

I'm integrating with some code that uses a void * for a context object (in this case a v8 Function) which I wish to cast back to a Function, but this is causing a compile error. How would you case this?

```
void callback(void* context) {
    Local<Function> func = static_cast<Local<Function> *>(context);
    func->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 1, 0);
}
```

Here is the code that register's the callback. Note that the fn gets passed into "callback" as a void *.

```
Persistent<Function> fn = Persistent<Function>::New(Handle<Function>::Cast(args[0]));
registerEvent(&callback, /* context*/ &fn);
```

Comment: `Local<Function> *func` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work you will need to cast `context` and assign it to a pointer value as such:

```
Local<Function> *func = static_cast<Local<Function> *>(context);
```

Comment: I now get another compile error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Function>’ has no member named ‘Call’